# Count the number of occurrences different final word types succeeding the string

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of lists like this

```
l = [['a', 'paragraph', 'is'],
     ['a', 'paragraph', 'can'],
     ['a', 'dog', 'barks']]
```

also suppose I have this smaller list `a = ['a', 'paragraph']` I want to count the number of occurrences different final word types succeeding the string. Therefore, the answer in this case should be `2` since 'is' and 'can' succeed the string 'a paragraph'.

I was trying to do something like this

```
l.count(a)
```

but that did not work and gives me 0.

Ill try to spell this idea out more clearly, we basically have this substring 'a paragraph' and there are two occurrences that have 'a paragraph' namely 'is' and 'can', therefore since there is 2 unique cases the answer is 2.

Comment: @RichardKYu The expected number is just a single number 2. Did I explain the idea correctly?

Comment: What is the relationship of the smaller list a to the larger list?

Comment: Very unclear, and "'is' and 'can' precede the string 'a paragraph'" isn't even true.

Comment: precede has been change to succeed, apologies, I think its clear now

Comment: *"succeed the string 'a paragraph'.* is still wrong, as that string isn't anywhere.

Comment: Seems like others understood what I mean by the question, if I did not articulate it more clearly then I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a set of all the desired words:

```
myset = {item[2] for item in l if item[:2] == ['a', 'paragraph']}
```

Then use `len()` of the set.

Comment: Thanks, was I not clear in my question?

Comment: It was more or less clear (after your edit to change "precede" to "succeed").

Comment: Would crash if `item` were `['a', 'paragraph']`.

Comment: @KellyBundy true, but that's a data cleanliness issue, and I often don't address those in my answers.  Easy enough to add `and len(item) > 2` as an extra condition in the set comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match each item in the list against the smaller list. We start by subsetting the larger list to match the size of the smaller list. If it doesn't match, we continue, ignoring that item. If it does match, we add the next item to a set. The set is important because it handles uniqueness.

```
items = [
    ['a', 'paragraph', 'is'],
    ['a', 'paragraph', 'can'],
    ['a', 'dog', 'barks']
]

check = ['a', 'paragraph']

check_len = len(check)
unique_words = set()
for item in items:
    if item[:check_len] != check:
        continue
    unique_words.add(item[-1])
print(len(unique_words))

2
```